# Copy files in Visual studio without git history

Tags: c#, git, visual-studio, bitbucket, visual-studio-2022

I noticed that whenever I duplicate a file in visual studio using copy paste, the git history of the original file is copied to the new file. How do we avoid this?

I expect the file to be considered as a new file rather than a clone of the existing file. Renaming the file doesn't remove the history.

Edit: I see that the old file's history is shown only in Visual studio's git history option. If I check the file history in bitbucket, it shows just the new file history. Even in visual studio code git plugin, the history is showing just what I expect. This seems like a bug in visual studio or some settings I need to turn off.

I am talking about the history we see by clicking the git history option in the context menu of the file in visual studio.
[Git history context menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5LuC.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Git does not store the history of files across copies/renames. It merely assumes that a file is copied or moved if it finds a similar file in the repo when it scans the history. So whether something is a copy is determined *while you inspect the history*, not when you commit a change. It is therefore a setting of the client how intensively git tries to identify copies.

Some git clients (e.g TortoiseGit, see image) allow changing the follow-rename behavior.

[image]

Comment: Yeah I was able to turn off the Follow renames in TortoiseGit to resolve the issue. But I think VS Git integration doesn't have such an option. Thank you @PMF